# When appending new data (points) in AGOL, the new points dont show up in the map?

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-pro, update, append, sharepoint

So my workflow was:

1. Open csv file in arcgis pro and plotting points on the map
2. Make a feature service and upload it to arcgis onine
3. Added 1 extra row to the csv file with new data.
4. Saved this csv file in sharepoint
5. Go to AGOL, to my feature service I uploaded here
6. Clicking on append data, then selecting my new csv file in sharepoint
7. Succesfully appended. It is shown in the table but not shown on the map

Anyone know why the point isn't showing up on the map ?

(Coordinate system is in RW new, when I click zoom to point in AGOL I can zoom to the location but nothing is to be seen there)

They are clearly in the table but not visible in the map.
[image]

Comment: What format is your x y location data in (lat/ lon, decimal degrees etc)?

Comment: the format is lat/lon 
example: x 213533    y 463824

Comment: Can you edit your answer and provide a sample of the data you are trying to append?

Comment: Could you please expand on your question? he way it is written now it seems as though you have a published map presenting data.Where is this data sitting - on a server or in AGOL?You also have an attribute table, that you have just appended data to.Have you physically added the spatial component? As in plotted the point and then appended the data to the main dataset?From your question it sounds like you have just added the attribute with X and Y to the spreadsheet.This will not add the point to the map.Which explains why you cant see it. how your data is stored will guide how this is answered.

Comment: Hi Keagan, I edited my question. Is it more understandable now ?

Comment: The coordinates for TEST look markedly different to all your other points. What projection are these points in? And is the TEST point record visible in the attribute table of the layer in AGOL?

Comment: You say the format is lat/long but maximum values of lat/long are +/-90 for lat and +/-180 for longitude.  You are clearly showing hundreds of thousands, which I suspect are metres. AGOL uses WGS 1984 Web Mercator (Auxiliary Sphere).

Comment: I used a different coordinate system in arcgis pro (RD new) and then I uploaded it to AGOL. The x,y were taken in this coordinate system. But it shouldn't be a problem

Comment: Please keep using the [edit] button beneath your question to try and make the precise and detailed steps that have led you to where you are stuck clearer. If "At the beginning [you] made a feature service via arcgis pro " then I think your question needs to include the detailed steps that you used to do that.  What happened when you tried to do your workflow on a newly created feature service?

Comment: I think you should simplify your test by taking SharePoint out of the loop.  If you only use the CSV from a Windows folder can you still reproduce the problem?  I suspect that some potential answerers may not have access to SharePoint and will not try to test while that is part of the test.

Comment: Yes I tried that too. Still the same problem. I think I have to update it via arcgis pro somehow